# Log monitoring is not working in Zabbix version 2.0.6

Tags: triggers, monitoring, zabbix

When I configure an item for log monitoring and then set a trigger for it, log monitoring doesn't work. I want to find the word `ERROR`and `ORA-4030`.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Install Zabbix 2.0.6.
2. Please have a look at the screenshot I have
   attached for the configuration.
3. Create an item with the Zabbix agent
   active.
4. Create a trigger based on that.  Then the trigger says "Trigger just added. No
   update so far". This remains like that.

When I check the `latest data` section, in the `last check` column is showing `Never`.

[image: Latest data section - Zabbix]

**My Item Configuration:**

[image: Item Configuration - Zabbix]

**My Trigger Configuration:**

[image: Trigger Configuration - Zabbix]

**My Log format:**

[image: Log file]

**Item Status:**

[image: Item status]

**Trigger Status:**

[image: Trigger Status]

**Configuration File of target host:**

```html
# This is a config file for Zabbix Agent (Unix)
# To get more information about Zabbix, visit http://www.zabbix.com

############ GENERAL PARAMETERS #################

### Option: PidFile
# Name of PID file.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# PidFile=/tmp/zabbix_agentd.pid

### Option: LogFile
# Name of log file.
# If not set, syslog is used.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# LogFile=

LogFile=/tmp/zabbix_agentd.log

### Option: LogFileSize
# Maximum size of log file in MB.
# 0 - disable automatic log rotation.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 0-1024
# Default:
# LogFileSize=1

### Option: DebugLevel
# Specifies debug level
# 0 - no debug
# 1 - critical information
# 2 - error information
# 3 - warnings
# 4 - for debugging (produces lots of information)
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 0-4
# Default:
# DebugLevel=3

### Option: SourceIP
# Source IP address for outgoing connections.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# SourceIP=

### Option: EnableRemoteCommands
# Whether remote commands from Zabbix server are allowed.
# 0 - not allowed
# 1 - allowed
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# EnableRemoteCommands=0

### Option: LogRemoteCommands
# Enable logging of executed shell commands as warnings.
# 0 - disabled
# 1 - enabled
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# LogRemoteCommands=0

##### Passive checks related

### Option: Server
# List of comma delimited IP addresses (or hostnames) of Zabbix servers.
# No spaces allowed. First entry is used for receiving list of and sending active checks.
# If IPv6 support is enabled then '127.0.0.1', '::127.0.0.1', '::ffff:127.0.0.1' are treated equally.
#
# Mandatory: yes
# Default:
# Server=

Server=xx.xx.xx.xx

### Option: Hostname
# Unique, case sensitive hostname.
# Required for active checks and must match hostname as configured on the server.
# System hostname is used if undefined.
#
# Default:
# Hostname=system.hostname

#Hostname=Zabbix server

### Option: ListenPort
# Agent will listen on this port for connections from the server.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 1024-32767
# Default:
# ListenPort=10050

### Option: ListenIP
# List of comma delimited IP addresses that the agent should listen on.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# ListenIP=0.0.0.0

### Option: DisablePassive
# Disable passive checks. The agent will not listen on any TCP port.
# Only active checks will be processed.
# 0 - do not disable
# 1 - disable
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# DisablePassive=0

##### Active checks related

### Option: DisableActive
# Disable active checks. The agent will work in passive mode listening for server.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# DisableActive=0

### Option: ServerPort
# Server port for retrieving list of and sending active checks.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# ServerPort=10051

### Option: RefreshActiveChecks
# How often list of active checks is refreshed, in seconds.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 60-3600
# Default:
# RefreshActiveChecks=120

### Option: BufferSend
# Do not keep data longer than N seconds in buffer.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 1-3600
# Default:
# BufferSend=5

### Option: BufferSize
# Maximum number of values in a memory buffer. The agent will send
# all collected data to Zabbix Server or Proxy if the buffer is full.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 2-65535
# Default:
# BufferSize=100

### Option: MaxLinesPerSecond
# Maximum number of new lines the agent will send per second to Zabbix Server
# or Proxy processing 'log' and 'logrt' active checks.
# The provided value will be overridden by the parameter 'maxlines',
# provided in 'log' or 'logrt' item keys.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 1-1000
# Default:
# MaxLinesPerSecond=100

### Option: AllowRoot
# Allow the agent to run as 'root'. If disabled and the agent is started by 'root', the agent
#       will try to switch to user 'zabbix' instead. Has no effect if started under a regular user.
# 0 - do not allow
# 1 - allow
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# AllowRoot=0

############ ADVANCED PARAMETERS #################

### Option: StartAgents
# Number of pre-forked instances of zabbix_agentd that process passive checks.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 1-100
# Default:
# StartAgents=3

### Option: Timeout
# Spend no more than Timeout seconds on processing
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 1-30
# Default:
# Timeout=3

### Option: Include
# You may include individual files or all files in a directory in the configuration file.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# Include=

# Include=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.userparams.conf
# Include=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd/

####### USER-DEFINED MONITORED PARAMETERS #######

### Option: UnsafeUserParameters
# Allow all characters to be passed in arguments to user-defined parameters.
# 0 - do not allow
# 1 - allow
#
# Mandatory: no
# Range: 0-1
# Default:
# UnsafeUserParameters=0

### Option: UserParameter
# User-defined parameter to monitor. There can be several user-defined parameters.
# Format: UserParameter=<key>,<shell command>
# Note that shell command must not return empty string or EOL only.
# See 'zabbix_agentd' directory for examples.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# UserParameter=
```

Please help me change my expression, let me know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Could you also provide the zabbix agent configuration for your target host?

Comment: @SimoneZabberoni I have added the configuration file as a snippet, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The trigger is correct, the real issue seems to be the data collection:

> When I check the `latest data` section, in the last check column is
>   showing `Never`.

The log item is correctly set up as an Active Check, but in the Zabbix Agent configuration the corresponding `ServerActive` parameter is missing.

From the 2.0 [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/log_items):

> Make sure that in the agent configuration file:
>
> - 'Hostname' parameter matches the host name in the frontend
> - Servers in the 'ServerActive' parameter are specified for the processing of
>     active checks

Modify your agent config to use both Server and ServerActive, pointing to the same ip:

```
Server=xx.xx.xx.xx
ServerActive=xx.xx.xx.xx
```

and restart the agent then check the latest data.

Additionally you can try to simulate the error with a simple `echo "ERROR: ORA-4030 Simulated" >> /var/log/alert.log`

Comment: So Server parameter will have my Zabbix server or target server IP?

Comment: You have to install the Zabbix Agent on the server where your `alert.log` resides, then configure both its Server and ServerActive to point to you zabbix **Server**'s ip address.

Comment: Thank You for your response I will test this shortly and let you know.

Comment: I have updated my config as per your suggestion, but still the same results.

Comment: Is there a way to check if this is supported or not for our version?

Comment: The documentation link I've sent you is for Zabbix 2.0, as you mentioned you are on 2.0.6. You have to double check your architecture: server status, agent status, the communication inbetween (don't forget the firewall rules!), the logfiles etc... Is that your first Zabbix setup/experience?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble but Zabbix 2.0.6 log monitoring is not available, it is Available from 2.0.13.

Comment: Not exactly. Zabbix log monitoring was already in place in 2.0.0, with 2.0.13 there are some improvements and additions. See **Important notes** under https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/log_items

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193648/discussion-between-ashutosh-and-simone-zabberoni).